# DateTimeFormatter cannot be applied to (java.util.Date)

Tags: java, exception, datetime-format, simpledateformat

I have decided to use a DateTimeFormatter instead of using SimpleDateFormat because I heard SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. I have declared DateTimeFormatter inside Constant file as follows.

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
```

and inside my class file my implementation like this.

```
String value = Constant.GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER.format(new Date(date.get()));
```

but seems like this is not correct implementation. Because it says format (java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor) in DateTimeFormatter cannot be applied to (java.util.Date) and  returns some error like this, "`java.incompatible.types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`"

I'm doing background research for this and still struggling to find the best way to resolve it. I like to know your ideas about this and it will help me to find a better solution. Really appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` is a part of java new time API. If you want to use `DateTimeFormatter`  than you should consider using `LocalDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date`

Comment: Something like `String value = Constant.GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Date(date.get())` would mean that `date.get()` returns a `long` with the milliseconds-since-epoch.

Since you're using `DateTimeFormatter` from the new Java Time API, you must give it a date object from that same API. `Instant` is such an object that can be created with a milliseconds-since-epoch value.

However, the format string you're using cannot be used with an `Instant`, so you first need to convert it to a `ZonedDateTime`, in the relevant time zone. In the code below, we'll assume you want the default time zone of the JVM, which is what the old `java.util.Date` API would have used.

```java
long epochMilli = 1598336543358L;

DateTimeFormatter GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String value = GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER.format(dateTime);
       // or:  dateTime.format(GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER)
System.out.println(value);
```

Since I'm in the US Eastern time zone, I get:

```
2020-08-25 02:22:23 EDT
```

As a single statement, you can write it as follows, but you'd probably format it over multiple lines to make it easier to read.

```java
// Single line
String value = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER);
```

```java
// Formatted for readability
String value = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli)
                      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                      .format(GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTimeFormatter` is a part of java new time API. If you want to use `DateTimeFormatter` than you should consider using `LocalDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date`

You can utilize the `DateTimeFormator` in your case like below:

```
String value = Constant.GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

Comment: Not useful, since it causes `java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal 2020-08-25T02:32:37.624048`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Constant {
    public static final SimpleDateFormat GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = Constant.GENERAL_TZ_FORMATTER.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

You can use, **`SimpleDateFormat`**  as mentioned above.

More about SimpleDateFormat ,you will get an idea by following [**`link`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: However, doing so is **highly discouraged** when writing new code in Java 8+. New code *should* be using the new Java Time API, as the old Date API is considered obsolete (because it was flawed). Replacing the use of `java.util.Date` would be a better option than replacing the use of `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but my guess is that it was down-voted for the reason I mentioned in my comment. Telling people to use an old out-dated API is not a useful answer, especially when you don't even warn about it in the answer, and because OP obviously can/want to use the newer API.

Comment: The question starts out by (wisely) stating that the questioner does not want to use `SimpleDateFormat` because it is not thread-safe. By using that class you are giving him exactly the errors in a multi-threaded program that he was trying to avoid from the outset. In addition `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class, and as @Andreas points out, long outdated.